# Multi-column content with floating image

Tags: javascript, css, frontend

Is it possible to do this only with CSS / JS?

[image]

I am already using CSS Multi-column to make the paragraphs in columns but I need to fit a floating image around the text.

It's not possible to break the content in multiple grid-like solutions. The post need to work like a magazine or printable newspaper when editing in softwares like Indesign.

Any JS/CSS solution will be good.

Answer (score 0):

I found the [CSS REGION](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-regions-1/) but unfortunately Chrome [left support in version 18](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-regions) (I need to support only Google Chrome).

Then https://github.com/FremyCompany/css-regions-polyfill save my day. I am working on an project to produce layout automation for magazines by the way.