# How can I have a block float centered, having text surround it to both sides?

Tags: css

I'd like to have a block of text centered within another block of text, having the outer block's text floating around the inner block to both sides:

[image]

How can this be done using pure CSS?

Comment: the property that can do this has not support and will probably never have any: https://caniuse.com/css-regions

Comment: @TemaniAfif - What you said about support, but the feature is css-exclusions, not css-regions.

Comment: @Alohci ah true, I confused between both..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to achieve this is with a polyfill like:
https://github.com/FremyCompany/css-regions-polyfill

CSS Regions was removed from css and CSS Exclusions is still in draft.

Another way to do this in the future is with CSS Shapes and shape-inside but is not supported yet: https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-shapes/index.html.

Same as: [Multi-column content with floating image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51274480/multi-column-content-with-floating-image/51277761#51277761)